# Cloudera Manager Yarn and Spark UI Not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have installed CDH 5.5.2 and it looks ok from Cloudera Manager, until I click on a Spark HistoryServer UI link or Yarn History Server UI link.  Those aren't working.  By not working, I mean they can't be reached at all from the browser.

I added in the file spark-defaults.conf the following lines

```
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://name-node-1:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://name-node-1:18088
```

I also cannot start the service with the command

```
sudo service spark-history-server start
```

When I go to Cloudera Manager -> Spark -> History Server, it is running and it is on name-node-1 and I am able to start it from Cloudera Manager.

Here is the output from the Spark, YARN, HDFS, SCM and Cloudera Manager logs

```
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   JobHistory  
Starting scan to move intermediate done files
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   StateChange 
BLOCK* allocateBlock: /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2016_05_24-22_29_59. BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194 blk_1073747330_6799{blockUCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-50e1e66a-ef5c-469e-ba0e-df1c259cbbae:NORMAL:10.128.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-4cacdc34-99a8-4d21-8744-40b5f5bd9919:NORMAL:10.128.0.4:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-09b4e549-2fcd-4ee4-8ccd-e5c15bdb3d7d:NORMAL:10.128.0.5:50010|RBW]]}
View Log File
data-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
Receiving BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799 src: /10.128.0.2:38325 dest: /10.128.0.3:50010
View Log File
data-node-2 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
Receiving BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799 src: /10.128.0.3:49410 dest: /10.128.0.4:50010
View Log File
data-node-3 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
Receiving BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799 src: /10.128.0.4:53572 dest: /10.128.0.5:50010
View Log File
data-node-3 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
PacketResponder: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
View Log File
data-node-3 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   clienttrace 
src: /10.128.0.4:53572, dest: /10.128.0.5:50010, bytes: 56, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_375545611_68, offset: 0, srvID: 2690c629-9322-4b95-b70e-20270682fe5e, blockid: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, duration: 8712883
View Log File
data-node-2 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   clienttrace 
src: /10.128.0.3:49410, dest: /10.128.0.4:50010, bytes: 56, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_375545611_68, offset: 0, srvID: 9a9d8417-9b4e-482b-80c8-133eeb679c68, blockid: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, duration: 9771398
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.128.0.5:50010 is added to blk_1073747330_6799{blockUCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-50e1e66a-ef5c-469e-ba0e-df1c259cbbae:NORMAL:10.128.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-4cacdc34-99a8-4d21-8744-40b5f5bd9919:NORMAL:10.128.0.4:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-09b4e549-2fcd-4ee4-8ccd-e5c15bdb3d7d:NORMAL:10.128.0.5:50010|RBW]]} size 0
View Log File
data-node-2 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
PacketResponder: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
View Log File
data-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   DataNode    
PacketResponder: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
View Log File
data-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   clienttrace 
src: /10.128.0.2:38325, dest: /10.128.0.3:50010, bytes: 56, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_375545611_68, offset: 0, srvID: a5a064ce-0710-462a-b8b2-489493fd7d8f, blockid: BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194:blk_1073747330_6799, duration: 10857807
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.128.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073747330_6799{blockUCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-50e1e66a-ef5c-469e-ba0e-df1c259cbbae:NORMAL:10.128.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-4cacdc34-99a8-4d21-8744-40b5f5bd9919:NORMAL:10.128.0.4:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-09b4e549-2fcd-4ee4-8ccd-e5c15bdb3d7d:NORMAL:10.128.0.5:50010|RBW]]} size 0
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.128.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073747330_6799{blockUCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-50e1e66a-ef5c-469e-ba0e-df1c259cbbae:NORMAL:10.128.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-4cacdc34-99a8-4d21-8744-40b5f5bd9919:NORMAL:10.128.0.4:50010|RBW], ReplicaUnderConstruction[[DISK]DS-09b4e549-2fcd-4ee4-8ccd-e5c15bdb3d7d:NORMAL:10.128.0.5:50010|RBW]]} size 0
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   StateChange 
DIR* completeFile: /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2016_05_24-22_29_59 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_375545611_68
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:29 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* addToInvalidates: blk_1073747330_6799 10.128.0.3:50010 10.128.0.4:50010 10.128.0.5:50010
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* BlockManager: ask 10.128.0.5:50010 to delete [blk_1073747330_6799]
View Log File
data-node-3 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Deleted BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194 blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330
View Log File
data-node-3 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Scheduling blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330 for deletion
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* BlockManager: ask 10.128.0.4:50010 to delete [blk_1073747330_6799]
View Log File
data-node-2 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Scheduling blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330 for deletion
View Log File
data-node-2 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Deleted BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194 blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   BlockStateChange    
BLOCK* BlockManager: ask 10.128.0.3:50010 to delete [blk_1073747330_6799]
View Log File
data-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Deleted BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194 blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330
View Log File
data-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsDatasetAsyncDiskService   
Scheduling blk_1073747330_6799 file /data/data01/dfs/dn/current/BP-1451272641-10.128.0.2-1459245660194/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir21/blk_1073747330 for deletion
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsHistoryProvider   
Replaying log path: hdfs://name-node-1:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_1464057137814_0006
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Running the LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager at 2016-05-24T22:30:15.155Z, forMigratedData=false
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Starting rollup from raw to rollup=TEN_MINUTELY for rollupTimestamp=2016-05-24T22:30:00.000Z
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Finished rollup: duration=PT0.729S, numStreamsChecked=38563, numStreamsRolledUp=1295
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsHistoryProvider   
Replaying log path: hdfs://name-node-1:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_1464057137814_0006
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Running the LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager at 2016-05-24T22:30:19.235Z, forMigratedData=false
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Starting rollup from raw to rollup=TEN_MINUTELY for rollupTimestamp=2016-05-24T22:30:00.000Z
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   CacheReplicationMonitor 
Rescanning after 30000 milliseconds
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   CacheReplicationMonitor 
Scanned 0 directive(s) and 0 block(s) in 2 millisecond(s).
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   LDBTimeSeriesRollupManager  
Finished rollup: duration=PT5.328S, numStreamsChecked=63547, numStreamsRolledUp=23639
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   metastore   
Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   metastore   
Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://name-node-1:9083
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   metastore   
Connected to metastore.
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   metastore   
Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 0
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   SearcherManager 
Warming up the FieldCache
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   SearcherManager 
FieldCache built for 192 docs using 0.00 MB of space.
View Log File
name-node-1 INFO    May 24, 2016 10:30 PM   FsHistoryProvider   
Replaying log path: hdfs://name-node-1:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_1464057137814_0006
```

Comment: Update your post with logs

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment,  which log should I get?  The spark one or scm one or maybe yarn

Comment: Hi I added some logs but I don't think it will be helpful.  I wonder how can I see the web server logs?  That's the log I need.

Comment: Have a look at this link (CLI) http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/admin_spark_history_server.html

Comment: This isnt a problem with cloudera actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with my cluster in the cloud.  I needed to create firewall rules for every single port

```
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-http --description "Incoming http allowed."  --allow tcp:80 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-http --description "allow-spark-ui."  --allow tcp:18088 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-hue --description "allow-hue."  --allow tcp:8888 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-spark-rpc-master --description "allow-spark-rpc-master."  --allow tcp:7077 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-spark-rpc-worker --description "allow-spark-rpc-worker."  --allow tcp:7078 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-spark-webui-master --description "allow-spark-webui-master."  --allow tcp:18080 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-spark-webui-worker --description "allow-spark-webui-worker."  --allow tcp:18081 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-address --description "yarn-resourcemanager-address."  --allow tcp:8032 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-scheduler-address --description "yarn-resourcemanager-scheduler-address."  --allow tcp:8030 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-resource-tracker-address --description "allow-yarn-resourcemanager-resource-tracker-address."  --allow tcp:8031 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-admin-address --description "allow-yarn-resourcemanager-admin-address."  --allow tcp:8033 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-webapp-address --description "allow-yarn-resourcemanager-webapp-address."  --allow tcp:8088 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-resourcemanager-webapp-https-address --description "allow-yarn-resourcemanager-webapp-https-address."  --allow tcp:8090 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-yarn-historyserver --description "allow-yarn-historyserver."  --allow tcp:19888 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-oozie-webui --description "Allow Oozie Web UI."  --allow tcp:11000 --format json
 gcloud compute firewall-rules create zeppelin-webui --description "Zeppelin UI."  --allow tcp:8080 --format json
```